# How do I prevent Chrome from saving / caching the chosen option in a <select> element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome

Inside of my React application, I have the following JSX code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class CategoryForm extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="category-form">
                <label>
                Category    &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;       
                <select value={this.props.selectedCategory} id="selectedCategory" onChange={this.props.handleChange}>                                  
                    <option value="Best">Best</option>
                    <option value="Controversial">Controversial</option>
                    <option value="Hot">Hot</option>
                    <option value="New">New</option>
                    <option value="Rising">Rising</option>
                    <option value="Top">Top</option>
                </select>
                </label>                 
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

It's a simple  element with  elements as children. The default value is initialized as, "Best". When the page is initially visited or refreshed, the value contained in the element reverts to "Best" (as expected), but when a user navigates away from the page and presses the back button, the  element retains whatever value was previously selected. How do I prevent this behavior? I'm trying to avoid forcing a re-render.

EDIT: I made the mistake of omitting code because I thought it would make the question more simple. Here's the state that I'm initializing in the constructor of the component, as well as the child component being created in the parent component. I modified my code according to the React documentation (and HMR) on controlled components, and I am still having the same problem.

```
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state= {
      selectedCategory: "Best",
      minScore: -100,
      numPosts: 25,
      subreddit: "",

      searchTerm: "",
      timeframe: "hour",

      postArray: [],
      animationTracker: false,
      selectedForm: "Category",

    } 
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.backendCall = this.backendCall.bind(this);
    this.changeForm = this.changeForm.bind(this);
}

\\ handle change method
handleChange(event) {
  // dynamically set the key of the setstate object to be equal to the id of the specific form

  let selectedCategory = event.target.id;
  this.setState({[selectedCategory]: event.target.value});
} 

\\ later on...
          {this.state.selectedForm === "Category" 
          ? <CategoryForm selectedCategory={this.state.selectedCategory} handleChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}/>
          : <TermForm handleChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
          searchTerm={this.state.searchTerm} timeframe={this.state.timeframe} />
          }
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqyGI.png)Here is a screenshot showing the problem in action. After pressing the to back button, the state is reinitialized (which should change the value to "Best"), but the value of my  element remains at whatever the user selected before navigating away from the page (in this case, "Hot"). In addition, if I modify the fields below (Minimum score and number of posts), then navigate away from the page, then press the back button, those fields follow the expected behavior and revert to the default state.

Comment: You can make the select a controlled component by giving it a value and save that value to state in the onChange function.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Please view my edit, and let me know if I implemented your advice correctly. I still believe this is not an issue within React.

Answer (score 0):

We might need to see more of your code.
I'm guessing that the handlechange() function sets the local state to the selected option. You'll need to clear that state to revert to the default option.

Comment: I added some code. As you can see in the screenshot, even though the state is reinitialized when the page is loaded, the <select> element still has the wrong value.